# Rails fails creating migration with NOW() default value to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timestamp, migration

Common way I use it is

`psql > ALTER TABLE transactions ALTER COLUMN date SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP\g`

it works fine.

In my RoR app I've tried to create migrations in two ways.

1.

```
class TransactionsSetDefaultDateChange < ActiveRecord::Migration
  change_column :transactions, :date, :datetime, :null=>false, :default=>'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
end
```

2.

```
class TransactionsSetDefaultDateChange < ActiveRecord::Migration
 execute <<-SQL
    ALTER TABLE transactions ALTER COLUMN date SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 SQL
end
```

Both failed. Any ideas why?

PS this case works with migration ("rake db:migrate") but is not applied correctly on "rake db:setup" (loses SQL statement)

```
class TransactionsSetDefaultDateChange < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
 execute <<-SQL
    ALTER TABLE transactions ALTER COLUMN date SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 SQL
 end
end
```

Comment: for the rake db:setup problem, try switching rails to sql schema: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Rails 5+ this works now

```
... null: false, default: -> { 'NOW()' } ...
```

Produces something like this in Postgresql Modifiers

```
not null default now()
```

Comment: Note that 'As of 10/15' means Rails 5 and above. This feature does not exist in Rails 4. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20005

Comment: The record is still created with nil fields when I try this, any idea why?
`add_column :works, :start_date, :datetime, default: -> { 'NOW()' }`

Answer (score 9):

Your question and answers here got me going. With Rails 4.2.4 and Postgres 9.3, the following migration code worked for me:

```
    create_table :goodies do |t|
      t.datetime :last_read_at, null: false
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE goodies ALTER COLUMN last_read_at SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
```

It produced a piece of working SQL:

```
    last_read_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course we can do it in postgres. Check out my example with current_timestamp. It creates column with "default NOW()". Strange that rails AR does not support such a core feature. But it's not the point. The solution is to fix model this way

```
before_create :record_date 
protected 
def record_date 
    self.date = read_attribute(:date) || Time.now 
end
```

So, thank you!

Answer (score -7):

a correct/clean/neat way to achieve this is with this migration:

```
class TransactionsSetDefaultDateChange < ActiveRecord::Migration
  change_column :transactions, :date, :datetime, :null=>false, :default=>'now()'
end
```

Therefore, you have:

- a standard migration, no specific sql commands which raise IrreversibleMigration.
- the standard postgresql way of setting current timestamps with timezone
- no need for triggers/filters at application level: Look at the output of Transaction.new.date
- works with other RDBMS like mysql

Comment: Actually, I've found that when you do this, and you inspect the constraint in the database, that now() has been evaluated and the default ends up being the value at the time its created, which if that is the behavior, then your answer is wrong. I can provide more info later if needed to back this up.

Comment: Dean is right, this doesn't work with Rails 4.1 and PG 0.17.1. The created column will default to the time that the migration was run, not the time that row is created.